# Is it possible to determine which version of windows XP goes with a licence key?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, license-key

Is it possible to determine which version of windows XP goes with a licence key?

If so, how?

Full story.  I got a windows xp licence key from MSDNAA while in college.  I also got a Windows7 at the same time.  I've only every used the Windows 7 and but now I'd like to use my XP key on a second box.  I installed the box with a windows xp pro SP2 disk I had lying around,  but it won't take the key.

Do I need an MSDNAA specific disk?
Should I try with XP Home?

I have some old OEM windows xp disks and keys but I've been told they will only work on Dell MoBo's (the computer is actually using a DELL HDD, DVD drive, and case, but the rest is new).

Comment: MSDNAA is almost certainly Windows XP Professional.

Comment: Some of the later Dell XP discs (SP2 and up) will install without a key on any PC, but may not activate, and will not pass WGA validation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try something like this:

http://techie-buzz.com/tips-and-tricks/find-windows-xp-product-key-from-installation-disc.html

In other words, you could possibly extract the license key from the installation disc.  I've never tried it, though, so I have no idea if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The key you got is likely locked to a MSDNAA type disk.  There are several types of disks - OEM, retail, Volume License...  Lots of the time keys will only work with a specific type of disk that they were generated for.  Try to get a new MSDNAA disk.

As far as the OEM keys - they are sometimes locked to the BIOS of the motherboard and look for strings like "Dell" or "HP" and won't work when they are installed on other systems.  Technically, they are locked to the specific motherboard they were purchased with.