# Site to lookup what Windows License Key allows?

Tags: windows, license-key

I have a bunch of old Windows XP Home license keys, but I'm not sure which are upgrades, which are for Retail RTM, and which are OEMs. I do have a XP Home RTM ISO I got of off MSDN

Is there a web site or some way I can see where the key came from plus what version of Windows (Home or Professional, x86 or x64) and type (RTM, OEM, Upgrade)?

Comment: You could just install the Windows version you want and then plug in license keys until one's accepted...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you match a Windows XP product key to a service pack release?](http://superuser.com/questions/186405/can-you-match-a-windows-xp-product-key-to-a-service-pack-release) or [Is it possible to determine which version of windows XP goes with a licence key?](http://superuser.com/questions/164494/is-it-possible-to-determine-which-version-of-windows-xp-goes-with-a-licence-key)

Comment: @Kromey But then that means I have to install Windows at least 3 times before I figure them all out. I don't have that much time lying around

Comment: @techie007 First one isn't related as I'm talking about release versions, not service packs. Second one is sorta a duplicate, but I'm asking more of a site than anything else

Comment: If you are looking for a website specifically, then SU probably isn't the place to ask. From the FAQ: "SU is not about... websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress"

Comment: @techie That rule is to prevent people from asking "How do I do X in Facebook?" Besides, if I asked this on Web Apps it would never get answered

Comment: @TheLQ - I don't think you're going to get an answer at all.  If someone or some site could reverse lookup/engineer the keys to a Windows version then they'd probably also be able to make a valid key generator.

Comment: @techie I was hoping there was some new Microsoft site that could do this. The old one doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

I use [Magical Jelly Bean](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) to find out all the product keys I used to install my various versions of Windows; it will describe the type of license key as well. :) Once you have that information (telling you what type of key it was (OEM, Upgrade, etc) you'll be able to look up any information you need to -- although, it sounds like it gives you the exact information you need without the google-fu'ing.

Comment: I use Magic JellBean already, its really good. The issue though is that it requires an existing install using the key. That means that I have setup an XP VM for each key and do everything manually, which is what I was trying to avoid in the original question (note since then I've done that)